# Callback doen't respond

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the following node :

```
    def set_set_goal_pose_callback(pose,em):
        print "i am here", pose.pose.position.x
    def listener()
        em=ratslam.experience_map_younes.ExperienceMap()
        sub_goal=rospy.Subscriber("/ExperienceMap/RobotPose",PoseStamped,set_goal_pose_callback,em)
        rospy.spin()

   if __name__=='__main__':
        rospy.init_node("RatSLAMExperienceMap')
        listener()
```

When I execute the node, the function set_goal_pose_callback isn't called.
What could I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270783/callback-doen%27t-respond/) by [Younès](https://answers.ros.org/users/29249/youn%C3%A8s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2017-09-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amstrudy](https://answers.ros.org/users/31757/amstrudy/) on 2017-09-12**:
Are you sure that you are publishing something to that topic elsewhere?

**Comment by [Younès](https://answers.ros.org/users/29249/youn%C3%A8s/) on 2017-09-12**:
No I don't publish any thing on that topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If nothing is published on that topic then that callback won't be executed. You need to publish information on that topic.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-15**:
@Younès: if this solved your problem, please click the check mark to mark it as correct.